# I am getting an invalid syntax error when using elif statement (Not an indentation error)

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

Should be an easy issue to solve. If you see my code below, the line that reads `elif target_2.got_away == True:` is returning an invalid syntax error. I have read other posts on this an all tips regard either not using an 'IF' statement before the elif or wrong indentation, which I believe this to be neither.

```
def refresh_window():
  if len(target_sprites) > 0:
   window.blit(bgr, (0,0))
  if len(target_sprites) == 0:
    window.blit(winner, (0,0))
  if target_1.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0)
  elif target_2.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
  elif target_3.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
  elif target_4.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
  elif target_5.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
  elif target_6.got_away == True:
    window.blit(loser, (0,0))
  player_sprites.draw(window)
  target_sprites.draw(window)
  for item in all_bullets:
    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLUE, (item['x']-5, item['y']-5, 10, 10))
    b_hitbox = (item['x']-10, item['y']-10, 20, 20)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLUE, b_hitbox, 2)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You should have a list of targets, rather than individual attributes. Then the `if` statement could be replaced by something like `if any(target.got_way for target in targets): window.blit(loser, (0,0))`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: which is why we tend to ask for *the complete traceback*, right? Because it *literally repeats the offending line*, right? I mean, you know it and I know it and the OP's Python knows it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line right above it doesn't have a second closing parenthesis. I often find that syntax errors are flagged on the line after they occur.